# How can I tell when SQL Server software (database engine) was most recently updated?

Tags: sql-server

One of our business partners decided to apply a SQL Server Hotfix in recent months and had enough access to do so.

How can I find out when this update was applied to our server?

I am familiar with a number of the methods for finding the version installed; today I am only interested in the DATE that that most recent version was installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can see when the SQL files were modified in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn" directory. (the directory depends on your SQL version).

In the properties of the file "sqlservr.exe" you can see "Date modified".

[image]

Comment: 1) I should have written "from within SQL Server".  I am "sysadmin" within SQL Server, but I have no access to the Windows Server on which it is installed.
2) It seems you are saying that the file modification date of SQLSERVER.EXE is altered during installation, so if I install a ten-year-old version of SQL Server today, then file SQLSERVER.EXE will have today's date in the modification date.  Is that correct?